# Сохранение данных при переходе на другую активность

Tags: android, android-edittext, onsaveinstancestate

Как сохранить данные, например в edittext, при переходе между активностями.

Comment: Объясните подробней

Comment: в одном активити в textview ввожу текст, потом перехожу на другое активити и вернувшись в первое активити, текст сохраниться

Comment: добавьте к своему edittext ИД, и данные будут сохраняться автоматически.

Comment: они сохраняются только при повороте экрана,  а при переходе на другую активность нет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821724/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE