# Возвращение результата с двух разных активити на одно

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: скриншот]

У меня есть 2 активити с TextView, которые с помощью requestCode и resultCode передают целые числа в TextView главного активити. Когда я поочередно ввожу числа в активити, их результат друг друга замещает в главном активити. Как сделать так, чтобы в AllFace.setText записывалась сумма с этих двух активити.

Comment: приложите код из активити (обеих), где вы пишете в `intent` для передачи на главную активность

Comment: прикрепил, на втором активити точно также.

Comment: имена переменных тоже идентичны? там где данные в `intent` пакуются...

Comment: нет, там индекс "2"

Comment: Тот код который я заскринил работает так, как и нужно. Я просто не знаю, как совместить в 1 результат 2 intenta. Переменные face_661_1 и face_661_2 нельзя перекидывать через кейсы

Comment: а я уж голову сломал что может быть не так)) вынести переменную суммы в активити и к ней плюсовать получаемый результат.
еще как вариант - вижу такое часто, в SharedPreferences писать получаемое для каждого и от этого брать сумму.

Comment: код нужно размещать в виде отформатированного текста, а не скриншотами.